# Laravel 5 Reset password notification won't send

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to implement the default reset password notification in my Application, but when I try to do password reset, nothing happens it will just say "We have e-mailed your password reset link!" but when I try to check my mailbox no email has been sent by my applications.

I did all necessary configuration on my application:
Email Driver,
Database Set-up

But there are some part of the Laravel i did changed:
User Model,
User Table Migration

Table Columns I did changed.

> id, name, US_EMAIL, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at,
>   EMP_POSITION, FACTORY, CONTACT, SIGNATURE, ONLINE, DATE_ONLINE, ADMIN,
>   LOCK

I did nothing on the reset password table, all fields are intact from the default laravel migration.

While I'm trying to debug my application it seems when I try to reset my password the application can successfully save the data to "password_resets" table but again I still cannot receive email reset notification.

I also did look to this trait, i tried to "Dump and Die" to see where the process goes after I click "send password reset link" and it seems the application can still proceed to this trait because it still display the "dd" message.

```
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

trait CanResetPassword
{
    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->EMAIL;
    }

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        dd('Test SendPasswordNotification');
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

I also did look to this but when I try to "Dump and die" to the "toMail" function it did not proceed. I was thinking maybe the application won't send an email because it cannot proceed to this class, I'm just guessing but i hope there's anyone can help me to this.

```
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
    /**
     * The password reset token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $token;

    /**
     * Create a notification instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
      dd('Test ToMail');
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', route('password.reset', $this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```

> Update: I can send email using my .env email settings, I think the
>   application can authenticate to the email server i used. The only
>   problem is i cannot receive email notification for the password-reset and also it does not display any error after i click "send password reset link".

Comment: uh, try sending non-reset password mail, just a plain generics mail and see what happens.

Comment: hi, I did and it's seems i can receive non-reset email, my only problem is on the password reset because i really cannot receive and it will not display any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found where the problem is.

When i change the email column from the user table to "US_EMAIL" there is a function from the Illuminate\Notifications trait that retrieves the email column.

```
Illuminate\Notifications

  public function routeNotificationFor($driver)
{


    if (method_exists($this, $method = 'routeNotificationFor'.Str::studly($driver))) {
        return $this->{$method}();
    }


    switch ($driver) {
        case 'database':
            return $this->notifications();
        case 'mail':
            return $this->email;
        case 'nexmo':
            return $this->phone_number;
    }
}
```

Solution:

```
on the "routeNotificationFor" function i changed this line "return $this->email;"
```

to:

> to " return this->US_EMAIL;"

Comment: Son of a gosh-darn female dog... You win at programming, sir.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should check your config/mail.php and .env to verify your email settings. My initial guess is you have it set to "mail" or "sendmail" and don't have either installed on your machine or server.

Maybe create a free account with an external email service (mailgun, sparkpost, etc) and set it up to rule that out?

---

EDIT: After reading again, I think you problem is this:

`public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->EMAIL;
}`

Based on the top of your question the "email" field in your DB is actually "US_EMAIL".

`public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->US_EMAIL;
}`

Comment: I think my email settings is fine since i can send a non-reset mail

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `.env` file and look for `MAIL_DRIVER`. 
Create a dummy email in email tester like [Mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/)

It should look like below using [Mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=usernamefrommailtrap
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepasswordfrommailtrap
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Now test it and check your dummy email in Mailtrap if you receive the email.

Comment: i can send email using my email settings, I think there's no problem with the .env email settings. I really don't know where's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things to check

First: `.env` file

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@email.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This is for production and [gmail](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin) message

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=usernamefrommailtrap
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepasswordfrommailtrap
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

This is for testing and [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) message

Second: `config/mail.php`

Be sure that your config file is set correctly with correct data's. Or make sure it is calling correct information from `.env` file

Third: Refresh

After editing `.env` file don't forget to stop the `php artisan serve` and run it again.
After editing `config/mail.php` file don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` to delete saved cache and create a new one

Comment: i tried to navigate this class Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword and check if i can go through. there are 3 functions the __construct,via and toMail, i tried to Dump and die on the first 2 functions and it was a success it can go through but on the last function the toMail i put the Dump and die it cannot go through

Comment: Oh.which mailing system are you using? gmail or mailtrap?

Comment: i use gmail, also i notice when i change back to the default "email" column name in user model since i renamed it to "user_email",  it was a success i can receive a password reset email.